# Split, regex or get value from JSON

Tags: javascript, regex, json, parsing, split

I have the following string / JSON:

```
Object {id-##: "##"}
```

Well, I want the digits from the JSON value. How can i get it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums = 'Object {id-##: "##"}'.match(/\d+/g);
```

The above will do.

`\d+` matches digits

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your json and then treat the values as you wish

```
var decoded = JSON.parse({id-##: "##"});


for(var in decoded){

   //decoded.var = "##"
   //var = "id-##"

}
```